# Weird shading issue with Eevee (shadow lines)

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I struggle with some shading issues. I made a little animation with little camera movement. On same frames there are weird shadow lines. Other frames which are almost the same, are totally fine. It only appears after rendering...

Here is a picture for comparison of the two frames:

[image]

I would be very glad for help.

Cheeerio
Robin

Comment: are you using motion blur?

Comment: yes, do you think its because of that? I will try without

Comment: I don't know but it looks like there's a bug with motion blur in Eevee, so maybe tweak the values a bit and see what happens?

Comment: I figured out that it was because I put a displacement on the plane

Comment: oh ok great then   ;)